# google authentication is stopped working after publishing my app.. getting errors

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting following errors,

I have already tried to copy paste new SHA1 key to firebase and also updated my *google-services.json* file in Android Studio.

> E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
>   E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
>   E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api

I am unclear why *wellbeing.api* is coming in error, what could be the relation between my app and that app? I dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your app, you are offered by the developer console to sign your apps for you. If you chose that option, your app will be published signed with a key that may be different from what you have in Android Studio.

Make sure you either refused that option or uploaded the keystore to the developer console.

Comment: Thank you, yes I have missed upload certificate SHA1. I copied upload certificate SHA1 from play and added in Firebase. problem was solved. thanks for your response. I have also updated json file.

Comment: where do i find the sha-1 in console ?